# Spring boot JPA decide cascading order of entities

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have 3 entity class defined as below:

```
@Entity
public class Rimorchio {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long idrimorchio;

@Column(unique = true)
private String targa;

// .... Getters and Setters

}


@Entity
public class Atk {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long idatk;

@Column(unique = true)
private String codice;

@Column(unique = true)
private String targa;

@OneToOne
private Rimorchio suggerito;

// .... Getters and Setters

}


@Entity
public class Trasportatore {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long idtrasportatore;

@Column(unique = true)
private String nometrasportatore;

@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
private List<Rimorchio> listarimorchi;

@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
private List<Atk> listaatk;

@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
private List<Autista> listaautisti;

// .... Getters and Setters

}
```

When I try to save in the database the Trasportatore class, i receive the following error:

```
   org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - 
   save the transient instance before flushing : 
   com.petroli.gestionefasipetroli.entities.Atk.suggerito -> 
   com.petroli.gestionefasipetroli.entities.Rimorchio
```

So, I have to save the Rimorchio instance before the Atk instance.
I have a structure with a Repository that extends JpaRepository and a Service that simply call

```
 repository.saveAndFlush(trasportatore);
```

How can I decide the order of insertion into DB to avoid this problem? Or there is another solution (possibly avoiding manually cascading operations) to achieve this goal?

Comment: Is there some reason you don't have cascade persist set on the oneToOne relationships?

Comment: Yes, because the Rimorchio into the Atk is not mandatory. If I insert the cascading there all works well (I have to remove the cascading from Trasportatore). The problem is that can exist an Atk without Rimorchio!

Comment: Cascade persist doesn't stop or affect that - it has nothing to do with mandatory or non-mandatory references, only what JPA should do if you call persist and it finds a reference to a non-managed object. If you have Atk that exist without Rimorchio instances, calling persist on them is required, but is a no-op for ones already persisted.

Comment: Yes, but if I add cascade persist on the OneToOne I have SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry. If I use cascade persist only in the OneToOne relationship I cannot insert a Rimorchio within a Trasportatore insertion.

Comment: are these instances different? You need to have your model fixed so that in X->Y->Z->X', X==X'. X won't have an ID set until after persist (or even after a commit or flush) so JPA has no way of knowing these represent the same data.  If  'targa' strings are meant to uniquely  identify an instance row, you might want to use them as the ID, and it might help you get a handle on reusing instances that are meant to be the same in this object graph.